# Probability of this basic event

Tags: probability

Hopefully someone can help me figure this problem out, thanks!

Rules:
**1.** There are 2 players who **randomly** select a team
**2.** There are only 2 team options. Eg **Hawthorn** and **Geelong**
**3.** The game between Hawthorn and Geelong is played and a team is **victorious**
**4.** Both teams have a .50 chance of winning each

The question is. What are the odds that:
**1.** Both players pick the same team and are **CORRECT**
**2.** Both players pick the same team and are **WRONG**
**3.** Both players pick opposing teams. (Eg one picks Hawthorn the other Geelong, or vice versa.)

I believe the odds are as follows:
**1.** 0.25
**2.** 0.25
**3.** 0.5 (as player 1 could choose Hawthorn while player 2 picks Geelong **OR** player 1 picks Geelong and player 2 picks Hawthorn)

My friends seems to think its a **.333** chance of each occurring. 
Keen to see the results thanks for your help!

Comment: There's not enough information to answer the question. We don't know how likely each of the teams is to win.

Comment: yeah sorry both teams have a 50% chance of winning

Comment: I updated the question with the probability of each team winning

Comment: You can accept my answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are correct. Your friend has made the fundamental mistake of assuming all events (in a given sample space) are equally likely to occur.

Comment: so .25, .25, .5? are the odds then? Thankyou so much!

Comment: @DobbyEmery Yes...

Comment: I would actually say that the friend made the mistake of miscounting the events.  That is, they did not recognize that #3 includes two options.